# Query bring lowest rank if client is under more than in 1 program

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find a query to bring the lowest rank number from a client if he/she is active under more than 1 program, if only active in 1 program then ignore this condition
I have the following query [Query1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyCLh.png)  from the code below

```sql
SELECT --PC.OP__DOCID AS LegacyClientProgramId,
       PC.ClientKey AS ClientId,
       PC.PgmKey AS ProgramId,
       CASE WHEN Date_Discharged_Program IS NULL THEN 4 ELSE 5 END AS STATUS,
       PC.Date_Admit_Program AS RequestedDate,
       PC.Date_Admit_Program AS EnrolledDate,
       PC.Date_Discharged_Program AS DischargedDate,
       TX.Rank
FROM FD__PROGRAM_CLIENT PC
LEFT JOIN LT__TXPLANHIERARCHY TX ON PC.PgmKey = TX.PgmKey
WHERE pc.ClientKey in ( SELECT ClientKey FROM LT__MIGRATE_CLIENT)
and pc.ClientKey  in (3634164,99589547)
```

as you can see it brings me 1 clientid(3634164) who is under 4 different programids(4,16,54,1,5) and another clientid(99589547) only on programid 158. I want to bring the lowest rank number for that client which I do
when I add a clause to the query which brings me this [Query1 with condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gxgm.png)

```sql
and tx.Rank = 
(
select min(txx.rank)
from  FD__PROGRAM_CLIENT PCC
LEFT JOIN LT__TXPLANHIERARCHY Txx ON PCC.PgmKey = TXX.PgmKey
where  pcc.ClientKey = pc.ClientKey)`
```

but I also want to bring the clientid(99589547) that has null on the rank. That client only has 1 program.
Is there a way to skip the condition tx.Rank if client has more than 1 programid? or client has null rank then still bring?  Thank you very much

I created a table for the clients that have more than 1 programid and tried doing a case statement like
case when clientkey in ( select clientkey from TableCreated) then do this

```sql
tx.Rank = 
(
select min(txx.rank)
from  FD__PROGRAM_CLIENT PCC
LEFT JOIN LT__TXPLANHIERARCHY Txx ON PCC.PgmKey = TXX.PgmKey
where  pcc.ClientKey = pc.ClientKey)
```

else ignore but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your logic is:
Bring me Lowest non-null rank row for a client, unless the client only has NULL rows, in that case, bring me the first one.
You don't mention what happens if client is in two programs but both Ranks are NULL but i'll let it slide, in that case we return the lowest Program ID.

The way to solve this stuff is to create a counter per Client ordered by Rank ID. The function for that is ROW_NUMBER:

```sql
select *
from (

    SELECT --PC.OP__DOCID AS LegacyClientProgramId,
           PC.ClientKey AS ClientId,
           PC.PgmKey AS ProgramId,
           CASE WHEN Date_Discharged_Program IS NULL THEN 4 ELSE 5 END AS STATUS,
           PC.Date_Admit_Program AS RequestedDate,
           PC.Date_Admit_Program AS EnrolledDate,
           PC.Date_Discharged_Program AS DischargedDate,
           TX.Rank,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PC.ClientKey ORDER BY case when TX.Rank IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, TX.Rank, PC.PgmKey) AS sortOrder
    FROM FD__PROGRAM_CLIENT PC
    LEFT JOIN LT__TXPLANHIERARCHY TX ON PC.PgmKey = TX.PgmKey
    WHERE pc.ClientKey in ( SELECT ClientKey FROM LT__MIGRATE_CLIENT)
    and pc.ClientKey  in (3634164,99589547) 
    ) x
WHERE sortOrder = 1
```

The only downside is that you can't use such window functions inside WHERE directly, so you have to wrap it in a subquery.

Comment: For the logic 'if client is in two programs but both Ranks are NULL then we pick the lowest pgmkey' is it possible to look at last submission. The OP__DOCID that I commented out is the documentID. So if it has 2 programs with rank NULL then look at max(op__docid) I put in inside the subquery but gives me error. Thank you again for your help

Comment: You have all the building blocks you need in the query, i'd rather not just solve it for you. Just need to change so the sortOrder becomes sorted by the logic you mentioned instead of the way i sorted it. Read how ROW_NUMBER works, put different columns in the order by and see what it generates if you remove the WHERE and see all values and not just sortOrder = 1